# Rotating a single pattern in a pattern with several patterns

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I created a few patterns in SVG:

- One that has vertical stripes (id: A)
- One that has horizontal stripes (id: B)
- One that has horizontal and vertical stripes (I did this by adding both patterns into one new Pattern, id: AB)
- And one pattern, with horizontal and vertical stripes but they are both rotated in a different way (A by 25° and B by 45°)

My SVG looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="1000px" height="1000px">
        <defs>
          <pattern id="A" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="25" height="25">
              <path d="M0,12.5 L25,12.5" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 0.45"/>
          </pattern>

          <pattern id="B" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="25" height="25">
            <path d="M12.5,0 L12.5,25" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 0.45;"/>
          </pattern>
          
           <pattern id="AB" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="25" height="25">
            <rect x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" fill="url(#A)"/>
            <rect x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" fill="url(#B)"/>
          </pattern>
          
          <pattern id="A@25deg;B@45deg" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%">
            <rect x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" fill="url(#A)" style="transform: rotate(25deg)"/>
            <rect x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" fill="url(#B)" style="transform: rotate(45deg)"/>
          </pattern>
        </defs>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100px" height="100px" fill="url(#A)"/>
        <rect x="125" y="0" width="100px" height="100px" fill="url(#B)"/>
        <rect x="0" y="125" width="100px" height="100px" fill="url(#AB)"/>
        <rect x="125" y="125" width="200px" height="200px" fill="url(#A@25deg;B@45deg)"/>
      </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: pattern]

This is how the last one should actually look but the transform: rotation() messes it up. The problem is that I can't use patternRotation on every single child-pattern because then I would have to create a new pattern every time. I don't want this because of performance issues. And I can't use patternRotation on the parent-pattern because then it rotates the entire thing and not just a single line.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Try setting the height and width to 100% ````<pattern id="A@25deg;B@45deg" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%">````

Comment: @Bedir looking better but still broken. Updated the snippet

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid rotation in the base patterns:

```html
<svg width="1000px" height="1000px">
 <defs>
   <pattern id="A" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="30" height="12.5">
     <path d="M0,0 L30,12.5" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 0.45"/>
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="B" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="20" height="20">
     <path d="M0,20 L20,0" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 0.45;"/>
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="MIX" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%">
     <rect x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" fill="url(#A)" />
      <rect x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" fill="url(#B)" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100px" height="100px" fill="url(#A)"/>
  <rect x="125" y="0" width="100px" height="100px" fill="url(#B)"/>
  <rect x="125" y="125" width="200px" height="200px" fill="url(#MIX)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thats not what I wanted. I have a few base patterns and now I want to use them in several different other patterns and every time there should be a different rotation. Seems like the only solution for this is creating already rotated base patterns as you suggested